# Ranges in MongoDB documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to define ranges in a MongoDB document so I can query by values belonging to a particular range.

For example, denoting a range by [min, max], if we consider a collection of three documents using this notation:

```
  {
    temperature: [-100, 10],
    sensation: "Cold"
  },
  {
    temperature: [10, 30],
    sensation: "Mild"
  },
  {
    temperature: [30, 50],
    sensation: "Hot"
  }
```

I would like to make queries of values within these ranges and see which documents fit in:

```
temperature = 25.6 -> sensation = "Mild"
```

I know I can store min and max values as separate values, but maybe someone can think in a more elegant and efficient way of defining indexable ranges in MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [**dot notation**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) with the index of `min` and `max` value inn your array.

```js
db.collection.find(
    { 
        "temperature.0": { "$lt": 25.6 }, 
        "temperature.1": { "$gt": 25.6 }
    }, 
    { "sensation": 1, "_id": 0 }
)
```